# One to many relations Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I've looked all over but I can't find an answer to this question.

I am saving a Podcasts and its related episodes to Parse but the following code only saves 1 episode and the podcast (I suppose every entry found in the for loop resets `currentP` and only the last value found gets saved).

```
 let currentP = PFObject(className: self.podcastClass)
    currentP["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    currentP["name"] = name
    currentP["artist"] = artist
    currentP["summary"] = summary
    currentP["feedURL"] = feedURL
    currentP["artworkURL"] = artworkURL
    currentP["artwork"] = artwork
    currentP["date"] = date

 let episodesToParse = PFObject(className: self.episodesClass)
    for episode in episodes {
    episodesToParse["showDate"] = episode.date
    episodesToParse["title"] = episode.title          
    episodesToParse["downloadURL"] =  episode.enclosures[0].valueForKey("url") as? String
    episodesToParse["showNotes"] = episode.summary
    episodesToParse["localPath"] = ""
    episodesToParse["isDownloaded"] = "no"
    episodesToParse["parent"] = currentP
}
 episodesToParse.saveInBackground()
```

If I use something like `episodesToParse.addObject(episode.date, forKey: "showDate")` then the following error is returned:

`[Error]: invalid type for key showDate, expected date, but got array (Code: 111, Version: 1.8.1)`

I'm not sure how to proceed. What I want is currentP to be saved as it is and all its episodes to be saved in a different class with a relationship to its parent (Podcast). I found tons of ways to do this if you're adding one episode at a time but not a whole bunch of them (I would like to be able to save 500 instance of `episodesToParse`at once.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean to be saved in a different class? You really want each episode to be in it's own class?

Comment: No, I want all episodes to go into one class. Each episode should be a different row and relate to its podcast parent

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can use PFObject.saveAllInBackground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that you save the `episodesToParse` after the loop. You have to move the `episodesToParse.saveInBackground()` inside the loop so that everytime the loop sets the properties of the episode the episode gets updated:

```
for episode in episodes {
    episodesToParse["showDate"] = episode.date
    episodesToParse["title"] = episode.title          
    episodesToParse["downloadURL"] =  episode.enclosures[0].valueForKey("url") as? String
    episodesToParse["showNotes"] = episode.summary
    episodesToParse["localPath"] = ""
    episodesToParse["isDownloaded"] = "no"
    episodesToParse["parent"] = currentP

    //Inside
    episodesToParse.saveInBackground()
}
```

Or you could use [`PFObject.saveAllInBackground`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/saveAllInBackground:) to save all objects:

```
var episodesToSave[PFObject] = []

for episode in episodes {
    var episodeToParse
    episodeToParse["showDate"] = episode.date
    episodeToParse["title"] = episode.title          
    episodeToParse["downloadURL"] =  episode.enclosures[0].valueForKey("url") as? String
    episodeToParse["showNotes"] = episode.summary
    episodeToParse["localPath"] = ""
    episodeToParse["isDownloaded"] = "no"
    episodeToParse["parent"] = currentP

    //Add to episode-array
    episodesToSave.append(episodesToParse)
}

//Save all objects in the array
PFObject.saveAllInBackground(episodesToSave)
```

Comment: I have done this, but in the event the podcast has 500 entries, it will call the network and save 500 times. Doesn't  sound efficient

Comment: Your second solution works, thank you. I had to change `var episodeToParse` to `let episodeToparse = PFObject(classeName: "Episodes")`